# Groovy Closure with optional arguments

Tags: groovy, parameters, arguments, closures, option-type

I want to define a closure which takes one argument (which i refer to with `it` )
sometimes i want to pass another additional argument to the closure.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could set the second argument to a default value (such as null):

```
def cl = { a, b=null ->
  if( b != null ) {
    print "Passed $b then "
  }
  println "Called with $a"
}

cl( 'Tim' )          // prints 'Called with Tim'
cl( 'Tim', 'Yates' ) // prints 'Passed Yates then Called with Tim
```

Another option would be to make `b` a vararg List like so:

```
def cl = { a, ...b ->
  if( b ) {
    print "Passed $b then "
  }
  println "Called with $a"
}

cl( 'Tim' )                    // prints 'Called with Tim'
cl( 'Tim', 'Yates' )           // prints 'Passed [Yates] then Called with Tim
cl( 'Tim', 'Yates', 'Groovy' ) // prints 'Passed [Yates, Groovy] then Called with Tim
```

Comment: @user1291235 no problem :-)  Added another possible solution

Comment: And if you do not want to change the closure body, you can name the first argument 'it' :-)

Comment: at least with 2.4.11 the default arg is ignored and does not compile with `@TypeChecked` :-( - with `@TypeChecked(value=TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)` it works again ... same with varargs version

Answer (score 3):

**hopefully this helps**

```
​def clr = {...a ->  
    print "Passed $a then "
    enter code here

}

​clr('Sagar')
clr('Sagar','Rahul')
```

Answer (score 0):

The variants from **[@tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12580502/1915920)** do not work with **`@TypeChecked`** (in a class context), at least with `Groovy 2.4.11` where the default arg is ignored and **does not compile** :-(

So other (admittedly uglier) solutions that would work in this case are:

1. **declaring the closure first** seems to work fine (necessary for recursions anyway):

   ```
   def cl
   cl = { ... }
   ```

   - at least in Eclipse Neon / Groovy-Eclipse Plugin 2.9.2 the code completion/suggestions do not work either way using the closure later on in the same code block => so nothing lost as far as I can say
2. with **`@TypeChecked(value=TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)`** it would work for both, but then you would loose the type checking on the method (or class, depending on where you put it)
3. declare **closure delegate `cl2`**:

   ```
   @TypeChecked
   class Foo { 

     static main( String[] args ) {

       def cl = { a, b ->
         if( b != null )
           print "Passed $b then "
         println "Called with $a"
       }
       def cl2 = { a -> cl( a, null ) }

       cl2( 'Tim' )         // prints 'Called with Tim'
       cl( 'Tim', 'Yates' ) // prints 'Passed Yates then Called with Tim           
     }
   }
   ```
4. transform **closure into class method**, e.g.

   ```
   @TypeChecked
   class Foo { 

     cl( a, b=null ) {
       if( b != null )
         print "Passed $b then "
       println "Called with $a"
     }

     static main( String[] args ) {
       cl( 'Tim' )          // prints 'Called with Tim'
       cl( 'Tim', 'Yates' ) // prints 'Passed Yates then Called with Tim           
     }
   }
   ```